# gcc does not read command line arguments from file

Tags: gcc, cmake, makefile

I am trying to build ZynAddSubFX using CMake, and it errored:

```
D:/work/zyn-fusion-build/src/zynaddsubfx/rtosc/src/rtosc.c:9:10: fatal error: rtosc/rtosc.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <rtosc/rtosc.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

This is the command (simplified):

```
gcc @CMakeFiles/rtosc.dir/includes_C.rsp -O2 -fPIC -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -MD -MT rtosc/CMakeFiles/rtosc.dir/src/rtosc.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles/rtosc.dir/src/rtosc.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/rtosc.dir/src/rtosc.c.obj -c /g/Projects/zyn-fusion-build/src/zynaddsubfx/rtosc/src/rtosc.c
```

File system tree:

```
.
├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   └── rtosc.dir
│       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       ├── build.make
│       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       ├── cmake_clean_target.cmake
│       ├── compiler_depend.make
│       ├── compiler_depend.ts
│       ├── depend.make
│       ├── flags.make
│       ├── includes_C.rsp
│       ├── link.txt
│       ├── progress.make
│       └── src
├── CTestTestfile.cmake
├── Makefile
└── cmake_install.cmake
```

I can cat (command) `CMakeFiles/rtosc.dir/includes_C.rsp`, and if I replace `@CMakeFiles/rtosc.dir/includes_C.rsp` to the file's content, it will not make any error.

I can't edit Makefile directly because CMake will regenerate all Makefiles.

What should I do to solve this problem?

---

Edit 1:

CMakeLists.txt example:

```
add_library(rtosc src/rtosc.c src/dispatch.c src/rtosc-time.c)
target_include_directories(rtosc PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

includes_C.rsp example:

```
-I"/g/Projects/zyn-fusion-build/src/zynaddsubfx/rtosc/include"
```

gcc --version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: How are you specifying that flag in your `CMakeLists.txt`?  [Edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: "gcc does not read command line arguments from file" - Gcc is definitely read command line arguments from the files specified with `@` prefix. This is noted in [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html). Probably, something **else** is wrong in your case, or you are using a compiler which is not true gcc (but has such name).

Comment: @StephenNewell Edited. Also added version info.

Comment: You still haven't showed the part of your `CMakeLists.txt` that adds `includes_C.rsp`.

Comment: @StephenNewell: The response file itself is generated by CMake automatically. There are switches which allow/disallow CMake to do that, but these switches are set in the platform files, not in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Learn something new every day I guess.  I build in silent mode so never noticed when the flags got replaced with the file.